# How to insert into a nested list

Tags: c#, .net

I initialize a list of list:

```
List<List<double>> List = new List<List<double>>();
for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
{
    liste_moyenne.Add(new List<double>(5));
}
```

I want to insert the values of a list (this list is generated by another function) like this:

[image: Insertion in a nested list]

for that I did this piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myList.Count; j++)
    {
        List[i].Add(AddSmthToWork(myList[j]))
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `AddRange` method?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the `AddRange` method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var listOfList = new List<List<double>>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            listOfList.Add(new List<double>(5));
        }

        foreach (var item in listOfList)
        {
            item.AddRange(GetList(5));
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < listOfList.Count; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < listOfList[i].Count; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"listOfList[{i}][{j}] = {listOfList[i][j]}");
            }
        }
    }

    private static IList<double> GetList(int maxCapacity)
    {
        var newList = new List<double>(maxCapacity);

        for (var i = 0; i < maxCapacity; i++)
        {
            newList.Add(i);
        }

        return newList;
    }
}
```

With the output:

```
listOfList[0][0] = 0
listOfList[0][1] = 1
listOfList[0][2] = 2
listOfList[0][3] = 3
listOfList[0][4] = 4
listOfList[1][0] = 0
listOfList[1][1] = 1
listOfList[1][2] = 2
listOfList[1][3] = 3
listOfList[1][4] = 4
listOfList[2][0] = 0
listOfList[2][1] = 1
listOfList[2][2] = 2
listOfList[2][3] = 3
listOfList[2][4] = 4
listOfList[3][0] = 0
listOfList[3][1] = 1
listOfList[3][2] = 2
listOfList[3][3] = 3
listOfList[3][4] = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/nested-list)

```
List<List<double>> nestedList = new List<List<double>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4/*myCount*/; i++)
{
    List<double> sublist = new List<double>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 4/*myCount*/; j++)
    {
        sublist.Add(/*myValue*/)
    }
    nestedList.Add(sublist);
}
```